# wordpress - wp query custom type/tax not displaying posts

Tags: wordpress

Taxonomy query on a custom post type isn't showing results.  Regular query on custom type display results.  I can assign the custom tax to the custom types.  When I run a query, I get nothing but an error.  I get this error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/folsom/wp-includes/query.php on line 2526
```

Here's my query:

```
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product-cat',
                    'term' => 'featured',
                    'field' => 'slug' 
                    )
            )
          );
```

**UPDATE: hit enter before I was done.  Am in the process to adding more info

**UPDATE: I made sure to add the taxonomy to the post type in the args, defined a priority to the tax so they registered first.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_product_taxonomies', 0 );

add_action( 'init', 'setup_custom_post' );
function setup_custom_post(){
$args = array(
    'label'                 => 'products',
    // Bunch of other stuff
    'taxonomies'            => array( 'product-cat' ),
    ),

);

register_post_type( 'product', $args );
}
```

Comment: Are you going to add anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have added wrong taxonomy parameter. Use 'terms' instead of 'term'. So your arguments array looks like below :

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product-cat',
                'terms' => 'featured',
                'field' => 'slug' 
                )
        )
      );
```

For more info visit http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters

Comment: Typos.  Always a typo... :/